# Download the latest artifacts of failed gitlab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I want to automatically load test results of my gitlab pipeline (basically one xml file) into my project management application. No direct connection between these two is possible. However the gitlab API offers the following options to download artifacts of a pipeline:

- all artifacts of the latest **successful** pipeline run (selected by job name)

> GET /projects/:id/jobs/artifacts/:ref_name/download?job=name`

- all artifacts of a specific job (selected by job id)

> GET /projects/:id/jobs/:job_id/artifacts

- a single artifact file (selected by job id)

> GET /projects/:id/jobs/:job_id/artifacts/*artifact_path

**My current situation is following:**

I have test reports which are saved inside the job artifacts when running the pipeline. The artifacts are created on every run of the pipeline independent of its outcome

> *gitlab-ci.yaml*
>
> ```
> ...
> artifacts:
>
>      when: always
> ...
> ```

The artifact I am trying to download has a dynamic name

> ./reports/junit/test-results-${CI_JOB_ID}.xml

If I now want to download the **latest** test results to a different server than the gitlab server, I have to realize that I don't know the latest job ID, which means:

- I can't access the artifact directly because it has a dynamic name
- I can't access the artifacts of a specific job
- I can access the artifacts of the **latest** job, but only if it was **successful**

This leaves me with the situation, that i only get to download the latest test results, if nothing went wrong while testing. To put it mildly, this is suboptimal.

**Is there some way to download the artifacts from the latest job run (without knowing the job ID), independent of its outcome?**

Comment: just some theory crafting - you can always persist the job logs in your package registry as artifact - and you can fetch a whole list via https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/packages.html#list-package-files - in this way you could also retrieve the outcome, when the job artifacts are gone. but depends on how often your builds are running, this can create quiet a lot of packages :)

Comment: First of all thank you for the fast reply. After i read the documentation you provided I checked my project properties and found an entry with "packages_enabled":true. If i read the API documentation correct this would be enough for the packages to be able to be created, but how do i tell my job to create the package? Is there some tag i have to set inside the yml file? I cant seem to find an answer to this in the API documentation...

Comment: Official doc works, https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#download-the-artifacts-archive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there some way to download the artifacts from the latest job run
> (without knowing the job ID), independent of its outcome?

In order to achieve this we will use the Gitlab API in combination with the `jq` package.

Let's break down this question into components.

Firstly, we need to find out the `id` of the `last` executed pipeline for this project. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines

```
GET /projects/:id/pipelines
```

For this call you will need your `access token`, if you don't have one already check
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#create-a-personal-access-token
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html#create-a-project-access-token

You will also need the `Project ID`

[image]

```
LAST_PIPELINE_ID=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/pipelines | jq '.[0].id')
```

Next we will retrieve the `job id` by providing the `job name` by using the following API
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-jobs

```
GET /projects/:id/pipelines/:pipeline_id/jobs
```

In your case you need to change the following example with `your job's name`, in this example let's call it `my_job`

```
JOB_ID=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/pipelines/$LAST_PIPELINE_ID/jobs | jq '.[] | select(.name=="my_job") | .id')
```

Now we are ready to actually retrieve the artifacts, with the following API

```
GET /projects/:id/jobs/:job_id/artifacts
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#get-job-artifacts

```
wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.17 (KHTML,like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/11.0.654.0 Chrome/11.0.654.0 Safari/534.17" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/jobs/$JOB_ID/artifacts" -O artifacts.zip
```

The artifacts are available as `artifacts.zip` in the folder you executed `wget` from

Combining them here for clarity

```
LAST_PIPELINE_ID=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/pipelines | jq '.[0].id')
JOB_ID=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/pipelines/$LAST_PIPELINE_ID/jobs | jq '.[] | select(.name=="my_job") | .id')
wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.17 (KHTML,like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/11.0.654.0 Chrome/11.0.654.0 Safari/534.17" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/jobs/$JOB_ID/artifacts" -O artifacts.zip
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me solve my problem. I have adjusted your proposed solution in two ways. First i have modified the first curl command to directly get the ID of the latest run of a job as we have job runs outside of pipelines in our project. And second i adjusted the commands to be able to be run in a batch file on windows. Here my final solution:

Comment: `@echo off`

`for /F %%I in ('curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" https://some-gitlab.ch/api/v4/projects/<project id>/jobs ^| jq ".[0] | select(.name==\"e2e\") | .id"') do set JOB_ID=%%I`

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" --output C:\Users\<myUser>\Desktop\e2e-results.zip "https://some-gitlab.ch/api/v4/projects/<project id>/jobs/%JOB_ID%/artifacts"`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. There is no need browser specific header. And `curl` can be used.